# Как написать регулярку для проверки на числа и буквы?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужна функция проверки логина. Как написать для него regexp?

Выражение должно содержать как числа, так и буквы. Все выражение должно быть от 2 до 10 символов. Но! Логин не должен **начинаться с цифры.**

Я уже написала кучу разных выражений, но ни одно не работает - `(([A-Za-z]+[^0-9])+\w){2,10}` - типа такого.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `/^[a-z][a-z\d]{1,9}$/i`, - `preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z\d]{1,9}$/i',$login)`. Все должно работать.

Comment: Вы знаете про https://regex101.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Например так](https://regex101.com/r/MJl3Fy/3):

```
[a-zA-Z]\w{1,9}
```

А если более строго (`\w` может включать, например, `_`), то:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]{1,9}
```

Попробуйте и так:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]{1,9}$
```

Comment: я попробовала, и получилось , но у меня корректно работает только если с 1 до 9

Comment: @КаринаСокол, приведите пример (код) как вы использовали регулярку

Comment: к сожалению функцию я удалила, ибо начала неправильно, пошла изучать регулярный выражения и застраля . я только что проверила вот тут https://regexr.com/  и если до 9 - то все отлично работает.

Comment: @КаринаСокол, понятнее не стало :) попробуйте так: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}$`

Comment: Данное выражение будет захватывать все после первых цифр, включая 11 символ, а значит выражение `1sdsf` пропустит, только исключив первые цифры.

Comment: @And, о, блин, точно :) Спасибо за замечание, не заметил и в глаза долбился :)

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, если требуется ограничение по количеству символов, то обязательно использовать т.н. якоря *(символы начала и конца строк)*: `^` и соответственно `$`.

Во вторых, для регистронезависимого поиска, а так же для сокращения записи шаблона, удобно использовать символьные классы, например `\p{Latin}` - это символьный класс для латинских букв, а `\d` - для чисел.

И наконец в третьих, в уточняющем квантификаторе нужно учитывать *все* символы, а не только ему предшествующие: `{1,9}`:

```
~^\p{Latin}[\p{Latin}\d]{1,9}$~
```

Comment: А теперь уберите мультибайтные символы и ваш пример перестанет работать, ах да, а если и в правду русские не нужны не логины не пароли, зачем брать все. К тому-же, у тс показаны только англ., о русских речи нет.

Comment: @And действительно... Подправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если отсутствуют необходимые знания и опыт по составлению регулярных выражений, то я бы сделал следующее:

1. Собираем список возможных недопустимых логинов
2. Собираем список возможных допустимых логинов
3. Заходим в какой-нибудь визуальный редактор регулярных выражений
4. Составляем выражение таким образом, чтобы допустимые попадали, а недопустимые не попадали

Можно воспользоваться, например, [вот этим тестером регулярок](https://regex101.com)

Тестовые списки логинов сохраняем на случай, если проскочит какой-то недопустимый логин. Тогда его можно будет добавить в соответствующий список и подрегулировать регулярку.